# Symfony 2, Service Container, import parameters

Tags: symfony

I have issue about Symfony 2 Service Container. Can I import to my service, parameters from another service by injection via service config? For example:

In services.yml in my bundle I want to get AsseticBundle parameters from app/config/config.yml:

```
#src/MyBundle/Resources/config/config.yml
   ...
   arguments:  [@service_container, %assetic%]
```

AsseticBundle parameters, that I need to get in my service class  construct:

```
#app/config/config.yml
  assetic:
  debug:          %kernel.debug%
  use_controller: false
  java: /usr/bin/java
  filters:
      cssrewrite: ~
```

Maybe someone found solution and can help me with that?

Best Regards,

Alex B.

Answer (score 1):

will something like this work for you ?

```
arguments:  [@service_container, %assetic.debug%, %assetic.use_controller%, ...]
```

Comment: Hi, Nuno. I tested it, but it works only for assetic.debug and assetic.use_controller, but for assetic.filters or twig.debug or swiftmailer.transport and other parameters it is not working. I will check, how DIC import parameters and write about it later. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this document about semantic configuration in symfony2 can help you http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/extension.html

Comment: You should not inject the `service_container` in your services. In your example you should rather inject only the services you need instead. See for example the "Avoiding your Code Becoming Dependent on the Container" section of http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html.